# from extjs array grid store, call csv file and store

Tags: extjs, grid, store

I have my code to upload my EXTJS array grid. However in store, I don't know how to call my data from a csv file that I have just uploaded (without saving).

Here's my controller upload.js:

```
Ext.define('APPLICATION.controller.upload', 
{
  extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() 
    {
        this.control(
        {
            'uploadview button': 
            {
                uploaded: this.uploadedfile
            }
        });
    },

    uploadedfile : function(form)
    {
        console.log('uploadedfile called, file: ' + form);

        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport',
        {
            items:
            [
                { 
                    xtype: 'displayview',
                    store: form //guessing here ******
                }
            ]
        }
        );
    }
});
```

Here's my view display.js:

```
Ext.define('APPLICATION.view.display' ,
{
    alias : 'widget.displayview',
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', 
    {
        fields: 
        [fieldData]
        /********data: myData*************/
    });
    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel'),
    {
        //extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
        //alias : 'widget.displayview',
        requires: 'Ext.grid.column.Action',
        xtype: 'array-grid',
        store: store,
        columnLines: true,
        height: 400,
        width: 800,
        title: 'Array Data Grid',
        viewConfig: 
        {
            stripeRows: true,
            enableTextSelection: true
        },
        columns:
        [columnLines]
    };
});
```

Comment: Can you describe your goal? What activities are you doing? Generally you get data from client (upload) and store it somewhere on server. Then you send data back to the client's grid (not a csv, but json e.g.).

Answer (score 0):

Your display.js is not correct. See line after your alias.

Comment: I know my store has problems, because I don't know how to pass the filename into display.js to use in the store. How do I solve that?

Comment: Please help! I can't find anything from the internet that gives me on how to open a uploaded csv file in store.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for [FileReader - API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/FileReader)